# Dictionary with lock or Concurency Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, dictionary

Which is preferred in a multi-threaded application:
 [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) with lock object 
or
 [Concurrency Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Which is efficient and why should I use one or the other?

edit 1: Storing Guid as key and bool as value.

edit 2: more than 2 worker threads and one UI thread.

Comment: It will depend very much on the situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dictionary-locking-vs-concurrentdictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949131/net-dictionary-locking-vs-concurrentdictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET - Dictionary locking vs. ConcurrentDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949131/net-dictionary-locking-vs-concurrentdictionary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read carefully about [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). It has some unobvious features.

Here are some of them:

- If two threads call `AddOrUpdate` there's no guarantees about which of factory delegates will be called and even no guarantee that if a factory delegate will produce some item that this item will be stored in dictionary.
- Enumerator obtained by `GetEnumerator` call is **not** a snapshot and may be modified during enumeration (that doesn't cause any exceptions).
- `Keys` and `Values` properties are snapshots of corresponding collections and may not correspond to actual dictionary state.
- etc.

So please read about [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) again and decide if this behavior is what you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

I would say you've got the following options.

Some new Framework 4.0 classes:

- [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). Work fast and reliable.
- [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx). It's *unordered collection* of objects, so it works faster, but suits if you don't need sorting only.
- [ConcurrentStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx). It's an implementation of the classic *LIFO* (Last-In First-Out) data structure that provides thread-safe access without the need for external synchronization
- [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx). It's a thread-safe *FIFO* (first in-first out) *collection*.

All new 4.0 classes work faster but have some features mentioned by *levanovd*. Performance comparison of these classes you can find [here](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/PerformanceCharacteristicsOfThreadSafeCollection.pdf&ei=e0KJUPPBMMPd4QSe5YDQDA&usg=AFQjCNFiqwg34_7Du233kJjkZRBTVzWDBg&cad=rja).

Some classic solutions from earlier versions:

- *Dictionary* + [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx). Simple wrap to *lock*
- *Dictionary* + [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx). Better than the previous one, because has got read and write locks. So several threads can read, and just one - write.
- *Dictionary* + [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx). It's just optimisation of the previous one.
- [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx). From my experience, it's the slowest method. Check [Hashtable.Synchronized()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized.aspx) method, it's a ready to go solution from Microsoft.

If I had a restriction of using Framework v3.5, I would use *Dictionary* + *ReaderWriterLock* or *ReaderWriterLockSlim*.

Answer (score 4):

When you are implementing a dictionary with a lock object, your main concern seems like thread safety. So it seems, a concurrentDictionary already manages this concern. I think there is no point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Not always. If speed is at a premium the manual locking might be better.

Comment: Depending on the situation, you may be right , on the otherhand, there is no applicable performance data on this situation. Custom testing may verify the performance gain(if any).

Comment: Then it depends what kind of objects you are storing in the dictionary, the expected length of the dictionary, the expected number of threads accesing the dictionary, implementation of custom locking,  the expected ratio of concurrent acceses,  etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think both will provide thread-safety but using a Dictionary with lock object will limit the number of thread that can access the Dictionary concurrently to 1.  While using Concurrent Dictionary, you can specify concurrent level (i.e. number of threads that can access the Dictionary concurrently).  If performance does matter, I believe Concurrent Dictionary should be your choice.