# Obtaining lock on a UI thread

Tags: c#

Is obtaining a lock on the UI thread a bad practice? For example I have a cache object which is being modified by both background threads and the UI thread. Any modifications to the cache is wrapped inside a lock. The pseudo code is as follows:

```
 public class Cache
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> _cache;
        private readonly object _onCache = new object();
        public Cache()
        {
            _cache = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
        }

        //Called by worker threads
        public void RefreshInBackground(IEnumerable<string> items, string key)
        {
            lock (_onCache)
            {
                _cache[key] = items;
            }
        }

        //Called by UI thread.Does this lead to any issues since UI thread is waiting on a lock?
        public void RefreshInForeground(IEnumerable<string> items, string key)
        {
            lock (_onCache)
            {
                _cache[key] = items;
            }
        }
    }
```

When the RefreshInForegound is called by the UI thread it has to wait on the lock (maybe), and the question is, is this a bad practice and if yes why?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the RefreshInForegound is called by the UI thread it has to wait on the lock (maybe), and the question is, is this a bad practice and if yes why?

If the operation can take a long time, this can be a problem, since it blocks the UI.

If *all* operations using the same lock object are short (such as the simple dictionary setters in your example), I would not worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

If it works fine like it is, I wouldn't change it.

If you have a performance concern then you can tweak it. Some points to improve:

#### Major

- Any potentially long-running operation shall be executed in a non-UI thread. Which means you need to remove `RefreshInForeground` from the class and use `Task`, `ThreadPool`, `BackgroundWorker` etc to run `RefreshInBackground` from UI.

#### Minor

- Switch to `Monitor` and `try-finally`, add a `timeout`. This is still not the best option as UI thread becomes blocked for at most the duration of a `timeout`. Still better than waiting forever.
- Use optimized lockers, such as [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)
- Use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) - lockless or non-blocking class

Answer (score 0):

For dictionary, there is `ConcurrentDictionary` class since .Net 4.0. See

[Dictionary as thread-safe variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993886/dictionary-as-thread-safe-variable)

For other type of thread-safe collection, you may see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx

For locking question, it is not a bad practice. The `lock` keyword is most convenient way to manage concurrency in trivial usage, but not the most optimal. For example, [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) might be better if you are doing single-write multiple-read synchronisation.