# Static collection dictionary in WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, static

I am writing tracing class to find the execution time of modules/methods. I have a class like this

```
public class Trace
    {
        static Dictionary<string, Stopwatch> watches = null;

        static Trace()
        {
            Dictionary<string, Stopwatch> watches = new Dictionary<string, Stopwatch>();
        }

        public static void Start(string key, string losgMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!watches.Keys.Contains(key))
                {
                    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                    watch.Start();
                    watches.Add(key, watch);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public static void Stop(string key, Object logMessage, string sessionId)
        {
            try
            {

                if (!watches.Keys.Contains(key))
                {
                    Stopwatch watch = watches[key];
                    watch.Stop();
                    //log goes here
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

since wcf is multithreaded environment and the 'watches' static variable scope is application level, If some one(new rqst from the differnt client) tries to execute the same method with same key i will not consider it and trace it. So what would be the best option in this case. Any suggestion would be helpful.

edit : I am current appending sessionId with key. Cant i resolve this issue without session id

Comment: From the looks of it you also have a `sessionId`, wouldn't it be more reliable to perhaps append this to the function key to make it unique?

Comment: Also, you need [locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx) in the Start and Stop methods, because they are reading/writing the dictionary while other threads might be working on it at the same time.

Comment: I trust you don't plan  to use this with any recursive methods.

Comment: "*yes I am currently doing so*" - If that's the case then there should be no issues with duplicate entries - assuming all requests have unique session ids that is.

Comment: yes i am not doing it in rec. method

Comment: @james one up to agree my logic

Comment: Why not just use a free profiler? You should also be aware that Stopwatch measures elapsed clock time, not CPU time.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any 3rd party profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't I resolve this issue without session Id

From the information provided, I would say no. If you have concurrent requests executing the same function call then you are going to get duplicate entries. The only way to avoid this is to ensure *all* keys are unique. I actually think using the session ID is required anyway, otherwise how can you map the function to the request?

Also, [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) isn't thread-safe (at least for writes), I would recommend using a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

Comment: if i use ConcurrentDictionary, dont i need to use lock before add/retreive/remove in ordinary dictionary?

Comment: "*don't I need to use lock before add/retrieve/remove*" - no, `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread-safe therefore can be accessed directly from multiple threads, all the locking is handled internally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949131/net-dictionary-locking-vs-concurrentdictionary -> Mark Byers claims it still needs lock. isnt it so

Comment: The point Mark Byers is making about race conditions e.g. you call `Contains` on the collection to check for a duplicate key, you then attempt to add that key if it doesn't exist. However, a concurrent thread could have added the same key inbetween calls. In your scenario, you don't have any reason to do this as all your keys will be unique. Also, `ConcurrentDictionary` has methods to avoid that sort of issue - [GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378674.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot.let me remove my lock and use ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: Just to clarify, the only thing you need to worry about is concurrent access to the collection, which `ConcurrentDictionary` should handle for you. Hope that helps.